# How do you upload an image from Gallery into an imageview?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-image, onactivityresult

so I am trying to upload an image i pick from gallery into my imageview that I have. But the image never shows up in the imageview? The program doesn't crash or anything. I used a toast message to see if onActivityResult grabbed the image or not, and it did. But it cannot load it into the image view.

Hopefully you guys can help, below is my code.

```
public class TakePhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private View snapButton;
    private ImageButton galleryButton;
    private int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private String user_image_path;
    private boolean pickedCamera = false;
    private ImageView myImageView;
    private ProgressBar myprogressBar;

    //GPS
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private LocationListener locationListener = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);
        setupCamera();
    }

    private void setupCamera()
    {
        snapButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.cameraActivity_CameraButton);
        snapButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        snapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        galleryButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraActivity_GalleryButton);
        galleryButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        myprogressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myPB);
        myprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraActivity_ImageView);


    }

    private void grabImageFromGallery()
    {
        Intent imageGetter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(imageGetter, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};//Array size of 1, and we put in a string
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            user_image_path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);//here we have our image path.
            cursor.close();

        }
        Picasso.with(this).load(user_image_path).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.cameraActivity_GalleryButton:
                grabImageFromGallery();
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">
    </include>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/cameraActivity_ImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_fb_2"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_camera_red"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/cameraActivity_CameraButton"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_fb_2"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_gallery"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cameraActivity_CameraButton"
            android:id="@+id/cameraActivity_GalleryButton"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/myPB"
            android:layout_below="@id/cameraActivity_CameraButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the Uri in `getData` directly? I think I used that and it worked fine. You should also look at `getClipData`, that one might be populated if you do multiple selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an image in image view from gallery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023788/how-to-load-an-image-in-image-view-from-gallery)

Comment: see my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loading local image you have path should be like this "file:///image_path.jpg".

Replace

```
Picasso.with(this).load(user_image_path).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);
```

with

```
Picasso.with(this).load("file:///"+user_image_path).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);
```

Comment: so I did replace my line with your line and it didn't work. But, if I use    Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);

Then it does work. So, is there a way Picasso can work with using the String imagePath or a file?

Comment: It will accept both see this for more detail  http://square.github.io/picasso/ actually picasso does Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to load image and show in imageview

```
public class LoadImage extends Activity
{
    Activity activity=null;
    Context context=null;

    Button header_left_btn=null;
    Button header_right_btn=null;
    TextView header_text=null;
    TableLayout image_table=null;

    ArrayList<String> image_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Drawable> image_drawable=new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    String path="";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.header);

        activity=LoadImage.this;
        context=LoadImage.this;

        header_left_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.header_left_btn);
        header_right_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.header_right_btn);
        header_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_text);
        image_table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_table);

        header_text.setText("Image Table");
        header_left_btn.setText("Select");
        header_right_btn.setText("Clear");
        registerForContextMenu(header_left_btn);

        header_left_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openContextMenu(header_left_btn);
            }
        });

        header_right_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                image_list.clear();
                image_drawable.clear();
                deletePhotos();
                updateImageTable();
            }
        });
    }

    public void deletePhotos()
    {
        String folder=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/LoadImg";
        File f=new File(folder);
        if(f.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files=f.listFiles();
            Log.v("Load Image", "Total Files To Delete=====>>>>>"+files.length);
            for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
            {
                String fpath=folder+File.separator+files[i].getName().toString().trim();
                System.out.println("File Full Path======>>>"+fpath);
                File nf=new File(fpath);
                if(nf.exists())
                {
                    nf.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Post Image");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.camer_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
          case R.id.take_photo:
              //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Take Photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              takePhoto();
              break;

          case R.id.choose_gallery:
              //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
              photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
              startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

              break;

          case R.id.share_cancel:
              closeContextMenu();
              break;
          default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
      return true;
    }

    public void takePhoto()
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
         File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LoadImg");

         if(!folder.exists())
         {
             folder.mkdir();
         }        
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         String new_Date= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+((c.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1)   +"-"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR) +" " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ "-"+ c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
         path=String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/LoadImg/%s.png","LoadImg("+new_Date+")");
         File photo = new File(path);
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));
         startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            if (photoUri != null)
            {
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Log.v("Load Image", "Gallery File Path=====>>>"+filePath);
                image_list.add(filePath);
                Log.v("Load Image", "Image List Size=====>>>"+image_list.size());

                //updateImageTable();
                new GetImages().execute();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode==2)
        {
            Log.v("Load Image", "Camera File Path=====>>>"+path);
            image_list.add(path);
             Log.v("Load Image", "Image List Size=====>>>"+image_list.size());
            //updateImageTable();
             new GetImages().execute();
        }
    }

    public void updateImageTable()
    {
        image_table.removeAllViews();

        if(image_drawable.size() > 0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<image_drawable.size(); i++)
            {
                TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tableRow.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
                {
                    ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
                    image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    /*Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_list.get(i).toString().trim());
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,500, 500, true);
                    Drawable d=loadImagefromurl(bitmap);*/
                    image.setBackgroundDrawable(image_drawable.get(i));

                    tableRow.addView(image, 200, 200);
                }
                image_table.addView(tableRow);
            }
        }
    }

    public Drawable loadImagefromurl(Bitmap icon)
    {
        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(icon);       
        return d;
    }

    public class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public ProgressDialog progDialog=null;

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...",true);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            image_drawable.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<image_list.size(); i++)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_list.get(i).toString().trim());
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,500, 500, true);
                Drawable d=loadImagefromurl(bitmap);

                image_drawable.add(d);
            }
            return null;
        }   

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            if(progDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progDialog.dismiss();
            }
            updateImageTable();
        }
    }
}
```

See [this](http://tjkannan.blogspot.in/2012/01/load-image-from-camera-or-gallery.html)

Comment: Thanks guys for the support! I will try this now

Comment: so I did replace my line with your line and it didn't work. But, if I use    Picasso.with(TakePhotoActivity.this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(myImageView);

Then it does work. So, is there a way Picasso can work with using the String imagePath or a file?

I want it to work with Picasso first, since I'll be using it more often around my app. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: try to use with Glide then picasso

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, I'll experiment around. Thanks for the support man, I really do appreciate the quickness of your response, seriously.