# unable to load image from gallery

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

When I open my gallery in order to select my photo in show. I got this following errors.and It returns null.
this my slideshow that extends ListActivity :

```
  public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Uri uri, ContentResolver cr, 
      BitmapFactory.Options options)
     {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment());

      Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, 
         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);         

      return bitmap;
   }
```

and here in another SlideshowEditor extends ListActivity:

```
    private class LoadThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Bitmap>
       {
  ImageView imageView; // displays the thumbnail

  // load thumbnail: ImageView, MediaType and Uri as args
  @Override
  protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params)
  {
     imageView = (ImageView) params[0];

     return Slideshow.getThumbnail((Uri) params[1], 
        getContentResolver(), new BitmapFactory.Options());
  } // end method doInBackground

  // set thumbnail on ListView
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
  {
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
  } // end method onPostExecute  
   }
```

and

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params)
  {
     imageView = (ImageView) params[0];

     return Slideshow.getThumbnail((Uri) params[1], 
        getContentResolver(), new BitmapFactory.Options());
  }
```

**my logcat :**

> An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "image:54305"
>           at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
>           at com.harshadjadav.slideshow.Slideshow.getThumbnail(Slideshow.java:328)
>           at com.harshadjadav.slideshow.SlideshowEditor$LoadThumbnailTask.doInBackground(SlideshowEditor.java:225)
>           at com.harshadjadav.slideshow.SlideshowEditor$LoadThumbnailTask.doInBackground(SlideshowEditor.java:215)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an image in image view from gallery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023788/how-to-load-an-image-in-image-view-from-gallery)

Answer (score 0):

In your `getThumbnail()` method, the `Uri.getLastPathSegment()` will return a `String` so you are getting this error, you are trying to parse a `String` object to `int`

You can update your method as

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail(ContentResolver cr, String path) throws Exception { Cursor ca = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID }, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {path}, null); if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) { int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)); ca.close(); return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null ); } ca.close(); return null; }
```

And can call like

```
getThumbnail(getContentResolver, uri.tostring)
```

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548645/get-thumbnail-uri-path-of-the-image-stored-in-sd-card-android

Comment: I cant understand :-((((((

Comment: would you please write it for me.

Comment: where I call this code getThumbnail(getContentResolver, uri.tostring) i got error when i call it

Comment: I cant call this method im my dobackground method

Comment: what is uri? it doesn't identify it

Comment: Uri is params[1] in your doInBackground method

Comment: would you please post doinbackground method. sorry i am new with android