# How can I get some data in 'onActivityResult' with ALBUM app?

Tags: android

In my app, I use default album app for get image.

Select image, I set that image at imageview in gridView.

```
public void getImageFromAlbum(int position){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_ALBUM);
}
```

I need '**position**' value in **onActivityResult**

If I use my custom activity, I use putExtra. **but this case, it can't**.
I think position value save class value. it will be run, but I don't want it...

---

## Solved

I just use global variable. it's so easy way. I think it's not perfect solution, but it works perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: @G. Kalender that is 'custom activity' case. isn't it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023788/how-to-load-an-image-in-image-view-from-gallery

Comment: @ADM i already know how to get imagefile.
that answer is not useful for me....

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getImageFromAlbum(int position){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra("bundle_id",position);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_ALBUM);
}
```

Comment: if i use this, i will write some code in starting activity.
but my case, i use default album app, i cant it!

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void getImageFromAlbum(int position){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
            intent.putExtra("bundle_id",position);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_ALBUM);
        }                                                               
    Get it in your onActivityresult like this :                                 
   int position = data.getIntExtra("bundle_id", -1); use it as your requirment.
```