# How to implement the function of getYourInputImage()?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

I'm working on eye detection project and I have trained my own model using Tensorflow Library, I have now the Tensorflow lite model.

I followed the documentation proposed by Tensorflow for how to integrate custom model MLKit firebase on the Android platform.

This is `CustomModelActivity.java` that I followed

https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/a7be1d9b6208d112d1bacbfff937c32c219124b5/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/mlkit/CustomModelActivity.java#L127-L128

I tried to implement this function by setting the image on imageview and I have tried to convert it to bitmap 
But I have encountered some issue ( false predictions ) on an image from the dataset.

I have posted many questions about this problem but I didn't get any answer.

I would like now to load the image from my gallery and get it, My question is:
How can I implement the last function `getYouInputImage()` ?

```java
 private Bitmap getYourInputImage() {
        // This method is just for show
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(0, 0, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that your question has a lot to do with `TensorFlow`. What you need is to load an image from a phone gallery using android API. You can find an answer for that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023788/how-to-load-an-image-in-image-view-from-gallery).

Comment: My question is related to Tensorflow because of load image with the right form ( preprocessing ) give good results.